# Angular6 makes API call to localhost from Server

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, angular6

I have an ndoejs/express app, which serves an angular6 application. Inside my angular6 app Im making http calls to my restAPI. If I host the App on localhost its working an connecting to my API.
But if i push the App to my VPS, the API call is also made to my local maschine. Is there a way to let the Angular App make the call to the VPS maschines running nodejs API? I would not like to change url everywhere in the app...
Im using Sequelize to connect to the databse etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Add a config for your different environnments...

Comment: Oh this is something I dont know. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add different `environment files`, that will hold specific settings for that environment.  Have a look at [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/becoming-an-angular-environmentalist-45a48f7c20d8) article.